# Convert GC log file timestamp to readable format

Tags: java

I want to convert below timestamp to readable datetime.

```
2221206.786: [Full GC (Allocation Failure)  1025663K->1025663K(1025664K), 1.9171581 secs]
2221208.719: [Full GC (Allocation Failure)  1025663K->1025663K(1025664K), 1.8723947 secs]
2221210.610: [Full GC (Allocation Failure)  1025663K->1025663K(1025664K), 1.9988764 secs]
```

How do convert a number like `2221206.786` to a date and time?

Comment: What's the format of the timestamp?

Comment: It wrote as seconds  elapsed

Comment: Since when? ___

Comment: @ikegami since the JVM was started

Comment: And is the date-time when the JVM was started available anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Your JVM was started with the following option:

```
-xx:PrintGCTimeStamps
```

which prefixes the elapsed time in seconds since the JVM was started, which for your examples was nearly 26 days ago.

If you want the date and time to be logged, use this option instead:

```
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
```

Or do your own date arithmetic with the existing log timestamp.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the old file to be in a readable format

Comment: It's OS dependant. In Linux for example you find the PID then `ps -f -p PID`

Comment: this process running on Linux os but I  have a lot of gc.log files that I can't address the timestamp so I need to check  those logs datetime

Comment: @Moustafa then AFAIK there's no way to recover the original datetime.